# POWERSHELL RDP file opening

Tags: powershell

How can I open an rdp automatically when it gets downloaded and make it as a windows service to run in background.

Here is the code for opening rdp session after it gets downloaded.

How can I achieve opening any file with .rdp extension without mentioning the name of rdpfile.

```
$RDPFile = "Drive:\Userpath\downloads\\*.rdp"

Invoke-Expression "mstsc.exe /h:850 /w:1000 '$RDPFile'"
```

Comment: Instead of launching .rdp files via PowerShell I would recommend using an actual RDP manager. Also, launching an RDP session in the background doesn't make much sense to begin with (since RDP is interactive by design). Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: And FTR, [do not use `Invoke-Expression`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).